# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value - NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: ios, swift, option-type, nsmutableurlrequest

When I try to run the below code snippet it works !

```
    let urlWithParams = "http://192.168.0.4:3003/manager/all"
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlWithParams)!)
```

But when I get the string from Settings.bundle Textfield the below code  doesn't work :

```
    let webServer:String = NSUserDefaults().stringForKey("priceWeb")!
    serverResponse.appendContentsOf(webServer)
    serverResponse.appendContentsOf("/manager/all")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: serverResponse)!)
```

When I execute

```
print(webServer);
```

the output is `http://192.168.0.4:3003` and when I execute

```
print(serverResponse);
```

the output is `http://192.168.0.4:3003/manager/all`

But still the error appears in the following line:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: serverResponse)!)
```

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

**Note : Please provide all the answers in swift**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You must encode your url as it contains special characters.

try this

```
let urlWithParams = "http://192.168.0.4:3003/manager/all"
let urlStr  = urlWithParams.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!  // or use let urlStr = urlWithParams.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLQ‌​ueryAllowedCharacter‌​Set())
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlStr)!)
```

for more reference see the Apple [Documents](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring)

Comment: What are the special characters in `"http://192.168.0.4:3003/manager/all"` that need to be escaped? I cannot see that it makes any difference to *this* URL string.

Comment: NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=%20http://192.168.0.4:3003/manager/all, NSErrorFailingURLKey=%20http://192.168.0.4:3003/manager/all, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL

got this error !

Comment: @Abiranjan: You seem to have a *space character* before "http", which does not belong there.

Comment: @MartinR oops yeah!! thank you that resolved the problem. It was just a spacing mistake.

Comment: also thanks to Anbu - this code stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) helped show the space.